# Derivatives of $f(x,t)=\varphi (x-at)+\psi (x+at)$

Tags: derivatives

Given that 
$$f(x,t)=\varphi (x-at)+\psi (x+at)$$
$$u=x-at$$
$$v=x+at$$

We need to prove that:
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}=a^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$$

We know how to calculate the derivative of the equation with the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=f'_u(-a)+f'_v(a)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=f'_u(1)+f'_v(1)$$

How I can calculate the second derviative ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. By the chain rule, one may write
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\varphi (x-at)+\psi (x+at)\right)=-a\varphi' (x-at)+a\psi' (x+at)
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}f(x,t)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(-a\varphi' (x-at)+a\psi' (x+at)\right)
=a^2\varphi'' (x-at)+a^2\psi'' (x+at) \tag1
\end{align}
$$ On the other hand, one has
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\varphi (x-at)+\psi (x+at)\right)=\varphi' (x-at)+\psi' (x+at)
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,t)&=\varphi'' (x-at)+\psi'' (x+at) \tag2
\end{align}
$$ From $(1)$ and $(2)$ one gets the announced result.